# Update a complex state object: React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state object in the following format where `keys` is an object and the `value` is an array of objects

```
this.state = { value : { keys: {}, values: [] } }
```

I am having trouble setting the state in the following function.This gets an object "data"  as parameter where in this function is called on a for loop.

The values is holding the latest values. Previous values are lost.

```
setData = (data) =>{
  let value = {};
  value.keys= { "key1": "1key", "key2": "2key"}
  value.values = {
     "value1" : data.value1,
     "value2" : data.value2       
  }
  this.setState({value})
}
```

Can someone help here?

Comment: why have you tagged `react-hooks` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not persisting the previous state value.

```
setData = (data) =>{
  let value = this.state.value;
  let newData = {};
  newData.keys= { ...value.keys, "key1": "1key", "key2": "2key"}
  newData.values = [...value.values, {
     "value1" : data.value1,
     "value2" : data.value2       
  }]
  this.setState({value: newData})
}
```